# Akka single node to cluster

Tags: akka

What issues can arise when I have an existing akka application that runs on a single node, and then in the future I need to use akka cluster?

Are there any design considerations or best practises I should follow when transitioning from a single node to a clustered akka design?  Or do things just work when you use cluster?

Answer (score 0):

The general advice is to start your design as if you were clustering from the start. In particular you need to pay attention to latency differences between cluster members so make sure what you're passing through the network (between actors on different machines) is not "huge". You also need to pay attention to location transparency (Akka solves this),  partial failure and concurrency. Each of these things can affect your design in significant ways so it is best to start out considering them and then optimize for the single-node cluster case.

- [Related Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/remoting.html#Distributed_by_Default) (see also referenced paper from Sun, 1994)